# Drawing to an offscreen buffer from an object function in p5js

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, p5.js

I'm trying to make a p5js code that has two visual outputs:

- one for the viewer
- one offscreen that is hidden, to be drawn and saved as a file only at the end of the simulation.

The drawing to the offscreen buffer works fine as long as I do direct calls to p5js functions such as circle(), or rect(), but as soon as I use an object it tells me that my object is undefined.

Here is the minimal code :

```
let canvas;
let offscreen;
let someobject;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400); // create main render view
  offscreen = createGraphics(400,400); // create offscreen buffer
  someobject = new SomeObject();
}

function draw() {
  
  // do & draw things onto main render view
  someobject.dothings();
  someobject.drawthings();
  
  if(true //end of simulation){
    offscreen.someobject.drawthings(); // draw to offscreen buffer
    offscreen.save(); // save file
    noLoop(); // stop simulation
  }
}

class SomeObject{
  constructor(){}
  
  doThings(){
    // does things  
  }
  
  drawthings(){
    circle(100,100,100);
  }
}
```

I understand the error that I get :

> TypeError: offscreen.someobject is undefined

Is there a way to share the objects between the canvas and the offscreen buffer ? Or is there a more obvious solution that I'm missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I can simply use the image() function of the p5js library to draw to canvas into the buffer like so :

```
offscreen.image(canvas,0,0)
offscreen.save(); // save file
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense:

```
offscreen.someobject.drawthings(); // draw to offscreen buffer
```

The `p5.Graphics` object `offscreen` does not have a `someobject` property and even if you had added that with `offscreen.someobject = someobject;` that wouldn't cause the drawing functions in `someobject.drawthings()` to draw to the `p5.Graphics` instead of the main canvas.

In order for this to work, you need to make `SomeObject` accept a `p5` instance in its render function:

```
let canvas;
let offscreen;
let someobject;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400); // create main render view
  offscreen = createGraphics(400,400); // create offscreen buffer
  someobject = new SomeObject();
}

function draw() {
  
  // do & draw things onto main render view
  someobject.dothings();
  // In global mode all of the p5js drawing methods that draw to the main
  // canvas are available globally, i.e. on the window object.
  someobject.drawthings(window);
  
  if(true /* end of simulation */){
    someobject.drawthings(offscreen);
    offscreen.save(); // save file
    noLoop(); // stop simulation
  }
}

class SomeObject{
  constructor(){}
  
  doThings(){
    // does things  
  }
  
  // This function takes an object with p5 drawing functions, such
  // a p5.Graphics object
  drawthings(p){
    p.circle(100,100,100);
  }
}
```